# Play .mov video from amazon in lightning

Tags: lightning, url, amazon, video, content-security-policy

I want to play **.mov** video from amazon in lightning.

Here is amazon presigned url:

> https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Activity%20Contents/test%20act%20Content/testVid47.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180829%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180829T082051Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=7ec66a41cc4c536ccc4abd42e5fea3621438563b114f72dd26f71c14eb4c4edd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Clicking the url will download the video which I want to play.

Here is how I am trying to play it:

```
    <video class="videoElement" controls="" src="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Activity%20Contents/test%20act%20Content/testVid47.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180829%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180829T082051Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=604800&amp;X-Amz-Signature=7ec66a41cc4c536ccc4abd42e5fea3621438563b114f72dd26f71c14eb4c4edd&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host" id="videoSrc" data-aura-rendered-by="116:560;a">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Here is what I see:
[image]

Here is the error I am getting in console:

> Refused to load media from 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Activity%20Contents/test%20act%20Content/testVid47.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180829%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180829T082051Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=7ec66a41cc4c536ccc4abd42e5fea3621438563b114f72dd26f71c14eb4c4edd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' *.visualforce.com https://zeddev-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com blob:".

It is clear that I am violating Content Security Policy, but I can not infer how to stop violating them from the error.

Comment: have you tried adding that URL on Content Security Policy Settings

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, what does that mean? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Am sorry I forgot to mention link and how to. ... https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, oh. Looks like you have a point here. I will try it and be back with the outcome. Thank you.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal. excellent. The link you provided did help. Will you post an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: I will post it as an answer... It will help others with similar queries reach a solution faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have put that URL in Content Security Policy settings in Salesforce. CSP setting determines which content from 3rd party sites can be played/viewed in Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5